# Strange problems while compiling

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have a problem in my xml when i try to deploy my project. This is mi code of my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.3.xsd">





        <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <!--    <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
            up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!--    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->


        <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <beans:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/EMPLEADOS" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="admin" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="admin" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
        <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>com.datadyne.spring.model.Empleado</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>


        <beans:bean id="empDAO" class="com.datadyne.spring.dao.EmpleadoDAOImpl">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="empleadoService"
            class="com.datadyne.spring.service.EmpleadoServiceImpl">
            <!-- <beans:property name="empDAO" ref="empDAO"></beans:property> -->
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.datadyne.spring." />


        <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>



    </beans:beans>
```

The problem that i have and i try to solve its this:

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 26 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 67; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: El comodín coincidente es estricto, pero no se ha encontrado ninguna declaración para el elemento 'tx:annotation-driven'.

But, why are happen this? in my beans declaration its declared the the variable 'tx'. Maybe this could be happen with some hit of spring dependencies? Im using spring 4.0.3 dependencies. Any idea? I give you my pom.xml for more information:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.srccodes.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVCHelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVCHelloWorld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

the order of `xsi:schemaLocation` values is messed up, try the following:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.3.xsd              
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

maybe you should use the same version for spring-tx, now you are using 4.3

Comment: I have multiple errors in my dispatcher-servlet.xml , cause i have copied code from one project, another project, etc. however youre right , my xsi was well not formed. Its a bit difficult because im making my own project, based on spring mvc + hibernate + jsf. Now i have to fix my entire xml, jeje. thanks testo testini.